# JSON to Multidimensional Javascript Object

Tags: javascript, json

I'm loading an external JSON file into javascript, the JSON file looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "name":"Apple",
    "year":8,
    "records_lost":12367232
  },
  {
    "name":"178.com",
    "year":7,
    "records_lost":10000000
  },
  {
    "name":"Accendo Insurance Co. ",
    "year":7,
    "records_lost":175350
  }
]
```

Eventually, I want to access the data via a Javascript object like this (don't mind the syntax). The point is that name will be a parent with its own meta-data.

```
"Apple":
  "year":8,
  "records_lost":12367232
"178.com":
  "year":7,
  "records_lost":10000000
```

This is the code I've already written for this part, which doesn't make name parent yet and only saves the last row of the JSON file into the array (`+=` instead of `=` would fix this, but delivers ugly values, obviously).

```
  function initJSON() {
    loadJSON(function(response) {
      var JSONParse = JSON.parse(response);
      var i;
      for (i in JSONParse) {
        JSONdata.name.i = JSONParse[i].name;
        JSONdata.year = JSONParse[i].year;
        JSONdata.recl = JSONParse[i].records_lost;
      }
    });
  }
  initJSON();
```

Thanks in forward.

Comment: Do you mean `JSONdata.name.i` or `JSONdata.name[i]`?

Comment: @MikeSamuel I'm not completely sure about that part. Read it sould be ``JSONdata.name.i``

Comment: `JSONdata.name.i` is equivalent to `JSONdata['name']['i']` so the meaning of the `i` after the `.` does not depend on `var i`.  That seems curious to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try utilizing `Array.prototype.map()` , `delete` operator

```js
var data = [{
  "name": "Apple",
  "year": 8,
  "records_lost": 12367232
}, {
  "name": "178.com",
  "year": 7,
  "records_lost": 10000000
}, {
  "name": "Accendo Insurance Co. ",
  "year": 7,
  "records_lost": 175350
}];

var res = data.map(function(val, key) {
  var obj = {};
  obj[val.name] = val;
  delete obj[val.name].name;
  return obj
});

document.getElementsByTagName("pre")[0].textContent = JSON.stringify(res, null, 4);
```

```html
<pre></pre>
```

Comment: Nice, this works. How do I only print the ``name`` value?

Comment: @BobWassermann Try utilizing `Object.keys()` e.g., `Object.keys(res[0])[0] // "Apple"`

Comment: Also, how do I access this from outside the function?

Comment: @BobWassermann Not certain interpret _"Also, how do I access this from outside the function?"_ correctly ? Can describe details ?

Answer (score 0):

it should be :

```
var i;
for (i in JSONParse) {
    JSONdata.name = i.name;
    JSONdata.year = i.year;
    JSONdata.recl = i.records_lost;
}
```

unless your loop was different:

```
var i;
for (i = 0; i < JSONParse.length; i++) { 
    JSONdata.name = JSONParse[i].name;
    JSONdata.year = JSONParse[i].year;
    JSONdata.recl = JSONParse[i].records_lost;
}
```

Comment: Both suggestions give me an ``Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'i' of undefined`` error

Comment: thats impossible do `console.log(response);`

Comment: Still. Am I calling it wrong? This is my current codebase: https://gist.github.com/BobWassermann/221409cdc65b5383dd87